# Let $A$ be a normal matrix. Show that $\|A\|^2 = \|A^2\|$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We know that $\|A\|^2 = \|A^* A\|$. How do we show $\|A^* A\| = \|A^2\|$?

Comment: See https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Norm_of_Adjoint

Comment: One direction is easy. Can you do that? Do you understand what $\|\cdot \|$ means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the matrix norm is the operator norm of the Hermitean scalar product, you have
$$
\|A\|^2=\lambda_\max(A^*A)
$$
and thus, using the properties of the spectrum of self-adjoint matrices,
$$
\|A^2\|^2=\lambda_\max(A^*A^*AA)\overset{(*)}=\lambda_\max(A^*AA^*A)=\lambda_\max((A^*A)^2)=(\lambda_\max(A^*A))^2=\|A\|^4
$$
$(*)$ because $A$ commutes with $A^*$ as per definition of a normal matrix.